# CSS animation classes in *ngFor?

Tags: css, angular, css-animations, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

(Angular  5.2, tns 4 , pure CSS animation.)

I'm struggling with a  freezy/stucky UI problem after a while.

I have a game with `4`  images which have a `".breath"` class which is nothing but animated `scaleX` and `scaleY` - infinitely.

After some user actions , I change those 4 images to *another 4 images*..

they are populated via `*ngFor` :

```
<Image *ngFor="let o of options;let i = index"
               [class]="'breath'"
               [src]="'~/images/keys/'+o+'.png'"
               (tap)="onKeyTap2($event,o )">
 </Image>
```

It is all working smooth. ( and I do  see 4 animated images).

But if I make some operations that causes the array to be repopulated , along the time , the UI become  stucky. ( eventually freeze).

I thought to myself  - "*maybe when the array is re-populated , the old animations doesn't stops and continue somewhere , causing this issue ?*"

So I've added a code that  *removes* the `.breath` animation class *before repopulate*.  - But still along the time , it becomes sticky and freeze.

But then I thought-  and created a test - I've *replaced*  `ngFor` with `4` manual `images`  ( where each also have the animated class) -

[image]

And it works smoothly (!!!) even if I make many many(many!!) operations .
So I guess that the problem with `ngFor` and old images with animation classes that are not disposed when repopulate  ( or something like that)

(BTW - i've already added the  `"markingMode": "none"`)

**Question:**

What is the right way of  dealing with `*ngFor`  images , where each have animation class ?